# Bot Framework Migration v3 to v4

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I can't find any documentation on bot framework v4 similar to the following implementation in bot v3 on calling conversation and manipulating the dialog stack through external API:

This is what the code in bot v3 looks like

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, messageToBot))
{
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //This is our dialog stack
    var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();
    //interrupt the stack.This means that we're stopping whatever conversation that is currently happening with the user
    //Then adding this stack to run and once it's finished, we will be back to the original conversation
    var dialog = new LoginCompletedDialog();
    var interruption = dialog.Void<object, IMessageActivity>();
    task.Call(interruption, null);

    await task.Forward(interruption, null, null);

    await task.PollAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    //flush dialog stack
    await botData.FlushAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Can someone give me how to implement this functionality in bot framework v4?

Comment: Your code looks a little strange to me, even for v3. Can you share any samples or documentation that your code is based on, and explain more about what it's supposed to do? What is the context here? What file is that code in?

Comment: That code interrupts the current conversation of bot and it can add dialog on top of the dialog stack. This is used for proactive messaging using autofac

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Some extensive documentation for migrating from v3 to v4 can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/migration/migration-overview

Documentation for proactive messaging in v4 can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message

Documentation for managing the dialog stack in v4 can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow

In v4, dependency injection is initialized in your Startup.cs file using the `ConfigureServices` method. You define your state storage and optionally define conversation state and user state. When those state objects are passed into your bot class or other classes then you can create state property accessors and create a dialog set from a state property accessor.

There is nothing special you have to do to have a new dialog interrupt the current dialog stack. If you just call `DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync` then the dialog will be added to the stack and the previous dialog will automatically be resumed when the interrupting dialog is finished.